# Calling Handlers in JQuery templating

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to call handler in Jquery templating.

I am using $(#templateid).tmpl(records);

I need to call handler while rendering every sub element inside the template. I could not find upto now. I am striving for more than 1 week. Can you please suggest me??

Otherwise instead of .tmpl() what shall i use?

Answer (score 0):

im not sure i follow the question... but i think you may be looking for a feature in tmpl"PLUS". you can add a function that is called every time the template is rendered...

```
var domObj = jQuery.tmpl(template, data ,{
    rendered:function(){
        alert('RENDERED NOW');
    }
}).appendTo(options.target);
```

see this link for more info
https://github.com/nje/jquery-tmpl/issues/closed#issue/32

Comment: you also have a typo... $(#templateid).tmpl(records); needs quotes around the selector